# GetElementsByTagName - No HTML

Tags: javascript

I did a `getElementsByTagName("li")` in my DOMDocument, but I don't have the inner HTML of each li elements, just the unlike a `getElementById`. How to get the HTML for a `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: What's this got to do with PHP? And why no JavaScript tag?

Comment: Because I'm using the DOMElement from PHP, not in JS

Comment: What browser are you running this in?  I seem to be finding that getElementsByTagName behaves this way only in IE 10. - no innerHTML property in the nodes returned.

Answer (score 0):

The word *Elements* in `getElementsByTagName` is *plural*.

It doesn't return an element, it returns a `NodeList`, which is like an array.

Loop over it (`for (var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++)`) and deal with each member in turn.

Comment: I know. I did a foreach on it. But each nodeValue doesn't contain HTML, juste the text in it

Comment: @Eko — Use `innerHTML` not `nodeValue` if you want the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. You have to loop through it to extract the `innerHTML` (make sure you really want the HTML, and not just the text!)

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { //x = the list of elements
    var derp = x[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Or if you wanna be fancy, use the prototype method forEach and call.

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"), function(element) {
    element.innerHTML;
});
```

I suggest replacing `innerHTML` with `textContent` however, since you said you wanted text.